# Exception while using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to populate some data to my custom grid in the BackgroundWorker. If the data is small then it is working fine but if the data is large, I am getting exceptions randomly. Sometimes I am getting “NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code” and sometimes I am getting “ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code”. Below I have mentioned some of the exceptions I am facing.

Basically what I am doing in Populate() method is that by using foreach loop I am assigning the values of each cell in my custom grid. This works fine when I am not using the BackgroundWorker. But while using the BackgroundWorker I am getting null values while assigning it to the cell. Hence lot of exceptions arises. I don’t know why this is happening. Is there any suggestions to overcome this?

Below is the code that I am using

**Code:**

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
{
if (this.PivotEngine.DataSource != null && this.PivotCalculations.Count > 0)
{

    // Populates the data for the grid. 
    // Without using the BackgroundWorker, the values are been populated properly.
    this.PivotEngine.Populate();        

}

};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
MessageBox.Show("Process is complete");
};

if (!worker.IsBusy)
{
  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**Exception1:**

```
Exception:
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base
StackTrace:
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.PopulatePivotTable() in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 5882
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.ResumeComputations(Boolean resetPivotCollections, Boolean shouldRefresh) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 2735
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.ResumeComputations(Boolean resetPivotCollections) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 2718
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.Populate() in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 2829
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PivotAnalysis.PivotGridControlBase.Populate(PivotEngine pe, Boolean checkLazyLoading) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Windows\Src\PivotGridControl\Core\PivotGridControlBase.cs:line 2990
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PivotAnalysis.PivotGridControlBase.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<ApplyRowCols>b__1a(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Windows\Src\PivotGridControl\Core\PivotGridControlBase.cs:line 3016
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
 InnerException:
```

**Exception2:**

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233086
Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
Source=mscorlib
ParamName=index
 StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.PopulatePivotTable() in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 5932
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.ResumeComputations(Boolean resetPivotCollections, Boolean shouldRefresh) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 2735
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.ResumeComputations(Boolean resetPivotCollections) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 2718
   at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.Populate() in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line 2829
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PivotAnalysis.PivotGridControlBase.Populate(PivotEngine pe, Boolean checkLazyLoading) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Windows\Src\PivotGridControl\Core\PivotGridControlBase.cs:line 2990
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PivotAnalysis.PivotGridControlBase.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<ApplyRowCols>b__1a(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args) in d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Windows\Src\PivotGridControl\Core\PivotGridControlBase.cs:line 3016
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
 InnerException:
```

Am I missing something while using the BackgroundWorker. Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Regards,

Anish.

Comment: Check that this.PivotEngine is not null inside your OnDoWork

Comment: Yes.  The problem is with 'this' which isn't defined in the backgroundworker.  You have to pass 'this' as a state object to the backgroundworker.  The backgroundworker is a separate process from the form you are running.  So you need to pass the instance of the form to the backgroundworker.

Comment: Your backgroundworker is assigning values to DataGridViewCell objects. The methods of this class are not thread safe. Could that be the problem? Shouldn't you use event BackGroundWorker.ProgressChanged to pass a new cell value to the UI thread and let the UI thread do the cell value change? Other method: Let the backgroundworker create and fill a binding source. Pass the filled BindingSource to the UI thread using event RunWorkerCompleted and let the UI thread assign the DataSource of the DataGridView to this binding source

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Harlod. I tried your method by filling the binding source in BackgroundWorker and then finally assign the values in my custom grid. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

While checking with the stack trace and all, it seems Populate() method itself called twice after the `ResumeComputation()` method.

> at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.PopulatePivotTable() in
>   d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line
>   5932    at
>   Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.ResumeComputations(Boolean
>   resetPivotCollections, Boolean shouldRefresh) in
>   d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line
>   2735    at
>   Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.ResumeComputations(Boolean
>   resetPivotCollections) in
>   d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line
>   2718    at Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base.PivotEngine.Populate() in
>   d:\Work_Vol4\svn\studio\trunk\work_area\GridWF\Engineer\PivotAnalysis.Base\Src\Engine\PivotEngine.cs:line
>   2829    at
>   Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PivotAnalysis.PivotGridControlBase.Populate(PivotEngine
>   pe,

You have to avoid such repeated recursive calls to stop this exception.